# Opening file with specific extension in python

Tags: operating-system

I am a self-learned coder and very new to this so please bear with me.
I am trying to open a .seis file with the seisop application.
the files are located in my documents folder and the excecutable for the application is in C:\Apps\

```
import os
seis_path = os.getcwd() + "\\seis_Samples"
app_path = "C:\\Apps"
print(seis_path)
print(app_path)
os.system("open -a /appc_path/to/SeisOp.exe /seis_path/to/*.seis")
```

Comment: What is going wrong? Is there an error message, stack trace, etc? Needs more details.

Comment: @paisanco I don't have any error message. The thing is, the file is just not opened after this

Answer (score 1):

in case this may be of interest to anyone, I ended up finding a solution to my problem after much troubleshooting :-D

The issue had to do with the fact that I needed to open the file as a subprocess.
The correct syntax to use is the following:

```
import sys, string, os
import subprocess as sp
APP = "C:\\Apps\\APP.exe"
file = os.getcwd()+"\\seis_Samples\\seisfile"
event = sp.Popen([APP, file])
```